# マクロ (javascript)でカーソル位置の文字コードを判別して条件分岐したい

Tags: emeditor

マクロ (javascript)でカーソル位置の文字コードを判別して条件分岐したいのですが、検索しても見つからないので、すみませんが教えて下さい。

Answer (score 1):

以下のようにマクロを書いてください。`ch` に文字が代入されます。

```
document.selection.Collapse();   // 選択範囲が存在する場合は、選択を解除
var x = document.selection.GetActivePointX(eePosLogical);
var y = document.selection.GetActivePointY(eePosLogical);
var str = document.GetLine( y );
var ch = str.charAt( x - 1 );
alert( ch );            // この行を書き換えてください
```